# How do I plot two normalized variables with one varying parameter as a 2d plot or a contour plot?

Tags: plotting, implicit

I'm trying to replicate a plot that has both (x,y) normalized variables, I've tried using *Evaluate* and *Contourplot* with no success.

I have set Rn=20, but it should be another variable.

Where Fn=fs/fr, Rn=R/Zn , Phi=x=Vo/Vin and alpha= Arcsin(-x/Rn)

Here is my code:

```
f[x_, Fn_] := 1/(1 - (Fn/(2*Pi))*(x/2 + ArcSin[-(x/20)] + 
              (1/x)*(1 - Cos[ArcSin[-(x/20)]])));
Parameters = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
Plot[Evaluate[f[#, Fn] &/@ Parameters], {Fn, 0.1, 0.9}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 0.9}, {0, 5}}]
```

(I hope I posted it correctly, I converted it to raw input form.)

[image: I should be getting this]
[image: The equation]